# Why is IllegalArgumentException thrown here by Method.Invoke?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, instance, illegalargumentexception

For a programming practical task, we are given an example .class file. We need to print out all methods that take 1 x int input and some printable output, and then allow the user to run that method with one input as given through the command line. However, when I try to invoke the method, an IllegalArgumentException is thrown.

My code that throws the exception:

```
// Request the user enter an integer and run the requested method.
private static void methodInvoke(Method inMethod, Class methodClass, Scanner scanner) throws 
NumberFormatException,IllegalAccessException,InvocationTargetException,InstantiationException,ClassNotFoundException
{
    Integer userNumber = 0;
    Object methodObject = methodClass.newInstance();

    System.out.println(inMethod.toString()); // Test to confirm printing the correct method.

    System.out.println("Enter a number to supply to: '" + inMethod.toString() + ":");
    userNumber = Integer.getInteger(scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.println(inMethod.invoke(methodObject, userNumber)); // Throws IllegalArgumentException here.
}
```

As some fail-safe checks I've done the following:

- Printed the integer to confirm scanner reads it correctly.
- Tested on an example file for which I know the code:

---

```
public class TestFile
{
    public int testMethod(int testInt)
    {
        return 2*testInt;
    }
}
```

Command line output when it occurs:

```
Enter a number to supply to: 'public int TestFile.testMethod(int):
1
Error: Invalid argument.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at MethodMetrics.methodInvoke(MethodMetrics.java:79)
    at MethodMetrics.main(MethodMetrics.java:29)
```

Any ideas as to the cause would be appreciated. Am I missing something obvious? :)

EDIT: Here's the code that selects the methods:

```
private static Method[] getIntMethods(Class classToTest) throws NullPointerException
    {
        int counter = 0;
        Method[] allFoundMethods = classToTest.getDeclaredMethods(); // Unnecessary to check for SecurityException here
        Method[] returnMethods = new Method[allFoundMethods.length];

        if(returnMethods.length > 0) // Only bother if the class has methods.
        {   
            for(Method mTest : allFoundMethods)
            {
                if(mTest.getParameterTypes().length == 1)
                {
                    if(mTest.getParameterTypes()[0].getName().equals("int"))
                    {
                        returnMethods[counter++] = mTest;
                    }
                }
            }
            returnMethods = Arrays.copyOf(returnMethods, counter);
        }

        return returnMethods;
    }
```

AND where "methodInvoke" is called from the main method:

```
System.out.println("Select a method with the method index from above: '(0) to (n-1)':");
selectedMethod = scanner.nextLine();
methodInvoke(foundMethods[Integer.parseInt(selectedMethod)], scanner);
```

Comment: and which line is 86

Comment: Hey @gen.Strash I've commented that in the first code block, it's the last line. :)

Comment: Clearly `inMethod` isn't expecting an `Integer` (or `int`) as its first argument. Since you haven't shown us how you get `inMethod`, we can't really help. If it really referenced a method accepting a single `Integer` or `int`, it would work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i've edited the question to show how I select the method and where the function is called.

Comment: Instead of printing `inMethod.getName() + "(int)"`, try printing `inMethod` itself, which will print the full method signature, and we'll *all* know exactly what method you're trying to invoke.

Comment: Why are you doing `Class.forName(inMethod.getDeclaringClass().getName())`, when `inMethod.getDeclaringClass()` is already the `Class` object you're looking for? --- And why are you printing the constructors, when `newInstance()` would have already failed if no no-arg/default constructor exists?

Comment: @Andreas sure I've fixed the bits of code where I was doing nonsensical things. With the suggestion given, the full method signature is printed by "inMethod.toString()" and gives "public int TestFile.testMethod(int)
", so it is indeed the correct method.

Comment: The following runs just fine: https://ideone.com/94RmO3

Comment: Thank you all. Much appreciated. Learned a few things about how not to use the Integer class tonight. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call is failing because you're passing a `null` value to an `int` parameter.

Javadoc of [`invoke()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) says:

> **Throws `IllegalArgumentException`** if the method is an instance method and the specified object argument is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying method (or of a subclass or implementor thereof); if the number of actual and formal parameters differ; **if an unwrapping conversion for primitive arguments fails**; or if, after possible unwrapping, a parameter value cannot be converted to the corresponding formal parameter type by a method invocation conversion.

Since converting `null` to `int` fails, you get `IllegalArgumentException`.

The reason you have a `null` value, is that you're calling the wrong method. Javadoc of [`Integer.getInteger(String nm)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger-java.lang.String-) says:

> Determines the integer value of the **system property** with the specified name.
>
> If there is no property with the specified name, if the specified name is empty or `null`, or if the property does not have the correct numeric format, then **`null` is returned**.

**Solution:** You should be calling [`Integer.valueOf(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

> Returns an `Integer` object holding the value of the specified `String`. The argument is interpreted as representing a signed decimal integer.

Comment: How you figured that out I don't know, however, thank you!

Comment: Works perfectly now, +1.

Comment: Just as a note `Integer.parseInt` should also work fine.